# Service worker over http: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script

Tags: angular, http, https, service-worker

I'm using a service worker with https not https for my angular 4 project. But I get this error :
**Service Worker registration failed:  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.**

Here is my service-worker.js

```
module.exports = {
    navigateFallback: '/index.html',
    stripPrefix: 'dist',
    root: 'dist/',
    staticFileGlobs: [
        'dist/index.html',
        'dist/**.js',
        'dist/**.css',
        'dist/assets/image/**.*',
        'dist/assets/image/client-home-carousel/**.*',
    ]
};
```

An in angular-cli.json:

```
"assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico",
            "service-worker.js"
        ],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Service Workers can only be used over an HTTPS connection. Are you using that or not? Also, the HTTPS certificate has to be valid.

As a sidenote, the code you're showing is not your service-worker.js. That code is some parameters and options to some SW library that then generates your service-worker.js based on those options. Most likely your actual service-worker.js is located in the dist directory and is updated as a part of your build process.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I didn't know that. But is it possible to have a service worker without https ?

Comment: @Melchia No, it's not possible. SW works only on top of an HTTPS connection no matter browser is used. You can use HTTP in development locally and bypass the HTTPS restriction/rule, check this out https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq Mark my answer correct if it helped you :-)

Comment: @pate hey, I have a question, I use Angular Service Worker. Unfortunately my testing servers dont have ssl and wont have. (its out of my control) The problem I have is that in testing my angular app gets cached, and not serves the one in the server. (even tho that the SW is not supposed to be working). any idea?

Comment: @pate How does one set up a name for an internal server on a private LAN and prove ownership thereof to a trusted CA? And by "locally" do you mean running a web server on a phone?

Answer (score 1):

So as pate mentioned "Service Workers can only be used over an HTTPS connection",

and if that specific DomException was happened locally, when accessing web resource at local machine with certificate, one of these latest version of browser launches may had helped:

```
open -a Opera.app --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://localhost:8111

open -a Brave\ Browser.app --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://localhost:8111

open -a Google\ Chrome.app --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://localhost:8111
```

Chromium browser did not start with these settings to allow to overcome this specific DomException for using SSL with service worker locally.

This person provided some insights as a story as well for this matter: https://deanhume.com/testing-service-workers-locally-with-self-signed-certificates/